# Keypad and alert view don't disappear when tapping outside in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift. I am creating an app where when user comes to the app, it shows the rating app alert box and then when user wants to input a number. At the same time, the keypad and the alert box comes on the view and there is no way to disappear from the screen. Please, help me solve this problem, where when 2 dialogs are up, let user disappear in order to respond either the keypad or the rating alert. Here is my code below. Thanks for any help.

Here is the image that is causing not to dismiss: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSgHS.jpg

> MainViewController

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

> AppDelegate for my rating app alert.

```
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let shortestTime: UInt32 = 1
        let longestTime: UInt32 = 10
        guard let timeInterval = TimeInterval(exactly: arc4random_uniform(longestTime - shortestTime) + shortestTime) else { return true }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.requestReview), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        return true


    }

@objc func requestReview() {
    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the override of touches began

Comment: It automatically wants you to insert the override. `Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword`

Comment: I mean to completely remove the touches began call not just the override part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, try my code in your project and edit as you wish

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    // *** Hide keyboard when tapping outside ***
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGestureHandler))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        }

    func tapGestureHandler() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

I hope it's work for you,

Comment: I try your way, but for some reason, it is not working. Check my updated question to see the image I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to hide what you want instead of "touchesBegan"